# Android: Is it possible to put an ArrayList<myObject> in a bundle?

Tags: java, android

I am creating an app to manage homework, and have a class called Assignment. I wish to add an ArrayList to a bundle, how should I do this?

Is it something to do with serialisable/parsable data, if so, all the data contained within an Assignment is simple data such as Strings and Integers (with the exception of a Course object which also contains simple data types)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this method [`Intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putParcelableArrayListExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E%29)

Of course the objects of the `ArrayList` should be parcelables!

Moreover, in case your data is huge, you should not use an intent to "carry them" to another activity. Think of another approach (i.e. a MemoryManager class to handle your data).

Comment: Thanks, and my Assignment class is parcelable :)